# Interface ADC with STM32F103 over SPI

Tags: microcontroller, adc, signal, communication, digital-communications

The ADC is ADS1256 which is a 24 bit 8 channel ADC. I will use 1 kHz sampling rate and there will be 3 ADCs, 21 channels used in total. The channels will be single ended. I plan to run the MCU on a 40 MHz clock. The MCU has 16 bit SPI frame so I need to retrieve the data from each channel part by part.

My question is would the MCU find the time to retrieve the converted data from all channels and run back to the first channel in time for the next samples conversion? Would there be data loss?

Comment: You seem to have everything you need to calculate it. What are you missing?

Comment: @Justme I have never done a calculation like this before so Im not sure what to include in the calculation. I dont know the actual times for conversion, the time required for ADC being ready again, how much time does it takes to tell the ADC to output the result etc.

Comment: There is just not enough info to answer. The SPI  bus frequency that must be used depends on what ADC master clock you use, and what frequencies below the ADC maximum you can select on the MCU. The data rate itself is not huge, 21 channels of 24 bits ar 1000 times per second, but the time of communicating how to select a channel for conversion, start a conversion, wait for end of conversion, and then read result, etc, all add up to the timing. As you have 3 chips you can stagger the operations on the single bus somewhat.